# Вопрос во втором классе

Tags: наречия, части-речи, существительные

Найди и подчеркни имя существительное.

*Папа взял нож и нарезал дольками.*

Интересует слово «дольками». Если это существительное, то почему?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, да. Существительное.

Не знаю, как сейчас учат в во втором классе, но вопрос "почему" в любом случае слишком философский для школы. Школьникам, думаю, будет достаточно ответить, что это ***творительный падеж существительного "дольки"***.

(+)===
Я бегло посмотрел в интернете, - никто подобные слова (дольками, колечками, ломтиками и им подобные) как наречия всерьёз не рассматривает.
Я, видимо, сильно переоценил глубину вопроса. Тем не менее сохраняю нижеследующий тест для общего обсуждения.

(++)===
А вообще вопрос упирается в то, что в начальной школе совершенно нет единого подхода - сужу по многочисленным обсуждениям в интернете на тему "наречие" или "существительное".

Вот пример того, как можно запутать подобный, казалось бы - совсем простой, вопрос. https://pedsovet.su/forum/194-6302-1

Тем не менее, исходя из того, что это второй класс и с понятием перехода одной части речи в другую дети еще не знакомы, а равно и из того, что множественное число нетипично для подобных "наречий", полагаю, что ожидаемый ответ - ***дольками - существительное***.

Конечно, на более высоком уровне можно поставить под сомнение, что это слово отвечает на вопрос "чем?", а не "как?" (сравните - "свернулся калачиком", "губки бантиком" и проч.). То есть здесь явно наречное значение, но от того слово не перестаёт быть существительным, хотя грань между существительным и наречием в таких конструкциях очень зыбка. Но не для начальной же школы все эти заморочки...

ПС Абсолютно "правильный" ответ может дать только учительница.

Comment: Всё верно: нарезал (чем?) дольками; часть речи - существительное, а (как?) ставим к члену предложения - обстоятельству.

Comment: @Людмила, не совсем понимаю смысл вашей реплики. Оно так, но суть-то проблемы не в этом. Тут же вопрос "почему?" стоит. Со школой-то, я надюсь, они разберутся так, как учительница скажет,  Нет четкого критерия для разграничения существительного и наречия. Ваш - точно не подойдет. "Птицы прилетают весною".  "Весною" - тоже существительное? "Котенок свернулся калачиком" - свернулся - чем? - калачиком. Существительное? Ну и т. д.

Comment: Дело в том, что наречие - самая новая часть речи, процесс образования ещё идёт. Если к слову возможны только вопросы наречия (где? когда? куда? откуда? почему? зачем? как? сколько?) - это наречие, если возможны и как?, и чем? - то это ещё существительное, но в предложении исполняет роль обстоятельства. Наречие - когда невозможен вопрос существительного. У нас возможен, значит, существительное в наречие ещё не превратилось, переход не произошёл.

Comment: @Людмила То есть калачиком - существительное??? (Свернулся чем?).

Comment: @Людмила И если можно, Вы не объясняйте мне такие вещи, вы просто посмотрите на всю ситуацию со стороны. Школьников во втором-третьем классе заставляют разбираться в вопросе, на который у академиков нет единого взгляда. И тут ваши правила явно не помогут. Вот, например, один такой методический материал. http://pedlib.ru/Books/4/0038/4_0038-69.shtml

Comment: Там так: шли шагом - наречие. Шли резвым шагом - существительное. Ваш критерий явно не для авторов (Борисоглебская Э.И.,и др.) писан.

Comment: Ну уж нет, вопрос чем? здесь будет не по-русски, только как? калачиком=как калачик.  Порезать дольками = на дольки, здесь возможно сказать чем? на что? и вставить определение: мелкими дольками.

Comment: А откуда я это знаю, что не по-русски? Не ладно, я черт нерусский, но ребенок во втором-третьем классе? И чем калачиком отличается от клубочком или шариком? "Летел самолетом" - это как или чем? А птицей?